# angularitics is not able to send uid in the request parameters after setting $analytics.setUsername( 'xxxx' )

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, angulartics

I have implemented `angularitics` to get information about event and page visits on my google analytics panel. I am trying to create a `user-id` view in the analytics panel. I have followed all the instructions mentioned in the following [link](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics-google-tag-manager) but it is not sending a `uid` in the request parameter in the data collection API. Because of this the `user-id` view is not showing any active user.
Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong or am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks